# Writing AT&T assembly to work with parity flag and offsets

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I have a certain set of instructions on x64 that end up either setting the Parity flag or unsetting it. I'd like to write some assembly that skips over an instruction of the Parity flag is set. From what I read from the manuals online `jpe` is an instruction that takes a jump if the parity flag is set and `jpo` is an instruction that takes the jump if the parity flag is unset.

I require execution to jump ahead by 3 bytes if the parity bit is set. Initially I tried the following, but it just jumps to the address `0x3` and not the offset from the RIP.

```
jpe 0x3
```

I realised that if I were using Intel syntax, I could do the following.

```
jpe $+0x3
```

However, that does not seem to work for AT&T and I get the following error message.

```
test.c: Assembler messages:
test.c:46: Error: operand type mismatch for `jpe'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not use a label? Anyway `jpe .+3` should work.

Comment: @Jester: Just a note: `jpe .+3` produces `7A 01` = `jpe short 0x01`. You must add the amount of bytes `jpe` consumes (=2).

Comment: @rkhb I know what it produces, it was not clear what OP wanted. Since `$+0x3` **also** produces this (in an assembler that uses `$` such as `nasm`) Anyway, I trust he can sort this out himself :)

Comment: The `jp` / `jnp` names for the same instructions might make your code clearer, if your parity condition doesn't really reflect even/odd parity of something.  (e.g. if the flag is set by SAHF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAS always wants the control over the jumps, see [the official documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dJumps.html#i386_002dJumps).

As Jester mentioned, you can use `.+3` as a sort of label, where the dot stands for the address of the actual line (like '$' in other assemblers). GAS will calculate the relative distance and the appropriate jump. There is one caveat: While the dot is the address of the actual line, the relative jump is calculated from the address of the next instruction. So `jpe .+3` produces `7A 01` = `jpe short 1`.

Another option is to use a label. I suggest a [local label](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html) which is even redefinable:

```
mov $0b110, %eax        # Parity = even
test %eax, %eax         # Set PF
jpe 0f                  # Jump forward to the next "0:"
.byte 0,0,0
0:                      # Local label
```